# working with entity framework query

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, one-to-many, entity-relationship, hibernate-mapping

I am working on entity to get the posts on user wall of posted by him and posted to him and posted by his friends

For this I have 4 tables

- userprofile
- post
- postcomment
- friends
- `Userprofile` table has `UserID`, `UserName`, `ProfileImg`
- `Post` table has `PostId`, `postedby`, `postedto`, `message`,`posteddate`
- `postcomment` table has `commentid`, `postid`, `commentedby`, `message`, `commenteddate`
- `friends` table has `id`, `Username`, `friendUserName`

and in entity

- userprofile to post--- 1 to many
- post to postcomment --- 1 to many
- userprofile to postcomment--- 1 to many
- post to friends --- many to many

I have used the query shown below to get posts posted by him and posted to him... but I am confused on how to include the posts posted by his friends.... please help me in this

```
          var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
                       where post.PostedBy == (int)Session["UserID"] ||
                       post.PostedBy == db.friends.all(something to get friends one by one)||
                       post.PostedTo == Session["UserName"].ToString()
                       orderby post.PostedDate descending
                       select new
                       {
                           Message = post.Message,
                           PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                           PostedByName = post.UserProfile.UserName,
                           ProfileImage = imgFolder +     (String.IsNullOrEmpty(post.UserProfile.ProfileImg) ? defaultAvatar : post.UserProfile.ProfileImg),
                           PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                           PostedTo = post.PostedTo,
                           PostId = post.PostId,
                           PostComments = from comment in post.PostComments.ToList()
                                          orderby comment.CommentedDate
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              CommentedBy = comment.CommentedBy,
                                              CommentedByName = comment.UserProfile.UserName,
                                              ProfileImage = imgFolder + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comment.UserProfile.ProfileImg) ? defaultAvatar : comment.UserProfile.ProfileImg),
                                              CommentedDate = comment.CommentedDate,
                                              CommentId = comment.CommentId,
                                              Message = comment.Message,
                                              PostId = comment.PostId

                                          }
                       }).AsEnumerable();
```

im returning ret to jquery to dynamically update the posts.... is there any solution or i have to completely change the query ??? I want to get the posts posted to the user and posted by the user and posted by his friends to display on user wall ... what is the best way to do it??

**UPDATE**
As of now i got this solution... there may be better solution for this.. if any please let me know..

```
 var ret = (from post in db.Posts.ToList()
                   where post.PostedBy == (int)Session["UserID"] ||
                   (from frnd in db.friends where frnd.userId == (int)Session["UserID"] select frnd.frndId).Contains(post.PostedBy)||
                   post.PostedTo == Session["UserName"].ToString()
                   orderby post.PostedDate descending
                   select new
                   {
                       Message = post.Message,
                       PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                       PostedByName = post.UserProfile.UserName,
                       ProfileImage = imgFolder +     (String.IsNullOrEmpty(post.UserProfile.ProfileImg) ? defaultAvatar : post.UserProfile.ProfileImg),
                       PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                       PostedTo = post.PostedTo,
                       PostId = post.PostId,
                       PostComments = from comment in post.PostComments.ToList()
                                      orderby comment.CommentedDate
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          CommentedBy = comment.CommentedBy,
                                          CommentedByName = comment.UserProfile.UserName,
                                          ProfileImage = imgFolder + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comment.UserProfile.ProfileImg) ? defaultAvatar : comment.UserProfile.ProfileImg),
                                          CommentedDate = comment.CommentedDate,
                                          CommentId = comment.CommentId,
                                          Message = comment.Message,
                                          PostId = comment.PostId

                                      }
                   }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Since you're immediately calling `ToList()`, your query will not be translated to store-query (SQL in this case) and will be executed by Linq-To-Objects after all `Posts` will be loaded in memory.

Comment: yes after all posts it will be loaded in memory and im returning ret to jquery to dynamically update the posts.... is there any solution or i have to completely change the query ???
I want to get the posts posted to the user and posted by the user and posted by his friends to display on user wall ... what is the best way to do it??

Comment: Which ORM you are using. Hibernate ??

Comment: @Suvasis thank you for reply... im a new to programming... actually i dint have clear idea about what ORM is...im using sql to store data and Im using MVC and knockoutjs to get the work done

Comment: There are two things. One getting required data from DB to your Service/Data Access Layer. Two getting fetched data from Service/Data Access Layer to User Interaction Layer. Concentrate one at a time if you are new to programming. As you having entity relationships better go for any ORM tool like hibernate or IBatis. There are tutorials on these. create a sample project you will get some idea

Comment: @Suvasis to me Nhibernate looks similar to EF.... can you tell me how i can change my code so i cant get the posts posted to the user and posted by the user and posted by his friends.... now with my code in question i can get the posts posted by the user and posted to the user but dont know how to write the code(relation) to get the posts posted by user friends.... Please help me in this on how to get that